# Prove that the last two digits of $a^{41}$ are the same as those of $a$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a$ be a natural number whose last digit is an element in the set {$1, 3, 7, 9$}.   Prove that the last two digits of $a^{41}$ are the same as those of $a$.

I know that I have to  use Euler’s theorem to show that $a^{41} ≡ a$ (mod $100$). But how do I write a proof for this?

Comment: Note:  $(10b+a)^{41}\equiv a^{41}+410a^{40}b\bmod100$

Answer (score 1):

The order of the multiplicative group $G=(\Bbb Z / 100 \Bbb Z)^*$ is the number of integers between $1$ and $100$ that are relatively prime to $100$.  There are $40$ of those.  Therefore, for any element $a \in G, a^{40}=1, \text{ so } a^{41}=a.$  Any two-digit number ending in $1, 3, 7, 9$ is in $G$ and any other number ending in those digits differs from such a number by a multiple of $100$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a=b+10c$, where $b\in\{1,3,7,9\}$.

Then, using binomial expansion and Euler's theorem ($b^{40}\equiv1\pmod{100}$),

$a^{41}=(b+10c)^{41}\equiv b^{41}+410b^{40}c\equiv b+10c=a \pmod{100}$

Comment: I don't quite follow why you add a 10b to the congruence. Could you explain in a little more detail please? Thank you!

Comment: @Elliot:  I edited to clarify

Comment: In fact, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function#Computing_%CE%BB(n)_with_Carmichael's_theorem $$\lambda(100)=20$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee:  I think that's true but not needed for this particular problem

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Got it, thank you!